# Getting error while trying to run ionic cordova build ios . Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.3)`:

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication" for ios
Running command: pod install --verbose

[!] Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.3)`:

- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.3/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.3/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json

[!] Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.2)`:

- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.2/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.2/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json

[!] Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.1)`:

- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.1/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.1/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
[!] Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.3)`:

- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.3/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.3/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json

[!] Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.2)`:

- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.2/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.2/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json

[!] Found multiple specifications for `FirebaseAuth (6.5.1)`:

- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.1/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
- /Users/vs/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth/6.5.1/FirebaseAuth.podspec.json
  at ChildProcess.whenDone (/users/vs/documents/ionicprojects/tripper-app/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
  at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
  at Pipe. (net.js:674:12)
  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

  ```
    cordova platform add ios exited with exit code 1.
  ```

Comment: The multiple specifications is an innocuous warning from multiple cocoapods sources. The real problem is the ERROR at the bottom from cordova-common/src/superspawn.js

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Any thoughts on how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

```
pod repo remove master
```

This will delete all your repo what is not working or broken.